# Titled paragraphs in IEEE conference paper templates

Tags: paragraphs

Titled paragraphs are very commonly used in CVPR and ICCV papers, like in here:

```
\section{Related Work}

\paragraph{Convolutional Neural Networks.} Such networks are also usually referred to as deep neural networks or deep convolutional neural networks.
```

With the CVPR/ICCV template, this is how it looks in PDF - the title is not indented (even if not the first paragrah in the section) and the title is in bold:

[image]

---

However, **the same** LaTeX code looks very different with the IEEE conference paper template:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is the usage of titled paragraphs common in IEEE conference papers? As in my opinion, they cannot function as CVPR/ICCV paper paragraphs do, due to the way they look - it is hard to notice them.
2. Is something else more common in IEEE conference papers, for example, subsections?
3. I can mimic the CVPR/ICCV titled paragraphs using `\noindent` and `textbf{}`, like below. Is it acceptable?

---

```
\section{Related Work}

\noindent \textbf{Convolutional Neural Networks.} Such networks are also usually referred to as deep neural networks or deep convolutional neural networks.
```

[image]

Comment: Whether this is acceptable depends in the standard of the conferences. Aesthetically, the last example does not look good to me because the section heading is not bold and so demands a lighter subsection heading, like the second example, but not indented.

Comment: Nice inspection about the relationship with the section title... I may need to use subsections, as the paragraphs are too ugly in this template.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is better to not skip levels,  There is also \subsection* if you want to lose the number.